# How to kill all command child processes and grandson in paramiko exec_command in case of timeout

Tags: python, ssh, timeout, paramiko

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.connect(<host details...>)
try:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd, timeout=timeout)
    err = stderr.channel.recv_stderr(sys.maxsize)
    exit_code = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
 except socket.timeout:
    # Need to kill all descendants of the exec_command process
```

I tried to add the bash timeout before command but have some chained command with';'

Comment: All processes should be closed along with the SSH connection. Aren't they? Do you properly close the connection?

Comment: I tried to run a script with paramiko that prints to a file, after the exception the python script ended but the bash script that was ran from paramiko continued to run and print to file. I think that I'll use bash sudo timeout <timeout> bash -c "<cmd>" although I prefer a python solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to run exec_command with get_pty=True, then when do
client.close() it kills all childs also